# Wrong number of arguments after defining a path in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-routing

I manually define a path in a rails helper as I had some conflicts when using a slug for the url. It's been working for a while quite well but now I suddenly keep getting a "wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)" error for it.

In the articles helper:

```
def edit_article_path()
"/articles/#{@article.id}/edit"
end
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I bet you call `edit_article_path` with argument, but didn't define it in method.

Comment: Yep you're right, I just noticed it.

Answer (score 0):

You should not rely on the `@article` variable because your method is a helper, which can be accessed everywhere in your views, and some (most?) views might not have the `@article` variable set.

I recommend you to use this implementation instead:

```
def edit_article_path(article)
  "/articles/#{article.try(:id) || article}/edit"
end
```

Use it like this:

```
# view
link_to article.title, edit_article_path(article)
# or
link_to article.title, edit_article_path(article.id)
```